# How to build levmar using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am using Windows XP and matlab version is 7.10.0.
I have the **levmar**(Levenberg Marquardt) package from http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/levmar-2.5.tgz

In the README file, we are told to compile in matlab using mex using the following command:
mex -DHAVE_LAPACK -I.. -O -L -L levmar.c -llevmar -lclapack -lblas -lf2c.

I downloaded **lapack.lib** , **blas.lib** and **f2c.lib** for windows

**UPDATE**:
The original error got resolved after I built a vc project file given in the package.
But now there are some error messages like :

```
levmar.lib(misc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgemm_ referenced in function _dlevmar_trans_mat_mat_mult
```

Comment: You need to link your libraries to the project. Just google for 'error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a file with a mex-function gateway? You can't just compile a c-function for Matlab; you need to do a little bit of work to take care of the I/O between Matlab and the c-code.

If you follow the steps outlined in [this document](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html), you should do fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link about the mex files

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [immoptibox](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~hbn/immoptibox/), which comprises Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out after searching a while and noticed that the levmar package included a vc project file which i needed to build and it created a file called levmar.lib .
But now I am getting some errors which involves messages like 'unable to resolve external symbols'